# akv2k8s is unable to inject secrets into environment

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, akv2k8s

I created a new AKS cluster and deployed a simple nginx pod. All works well. Then I added a secret injected through the environment and the `replicaSet` fails to start with the following error:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/chip/toolbox/k8s [test ≡ +0 ~2 -0 !]$ k describe rs toolbox-78544646dd | tail -1
  Warning  FailedCreate  26s   replicaset-controller  Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "pods.env-injector.admission.spv.no": failed to call webhook: an error on the server ("{\"response\":{\"uid\":\"2e772ecb-e618-42f8-9273-a43a5b17ac52\",\"allowed\":false,\"status\":{\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"message\":\"failed to get auto cmd, error: GET https://app541deploycr.azurecr.io/oauth2/token?scope=repository%3Achip%2Ftoolbox%3Apull\\u0026service=app541deploycr.azurecr.io: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.\\ncannot fetch image descriptor\\ngithub.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes/pkg/docker/registry.getImageConfig\\n\\t/go/src/github.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes/pkg/docker/registry/registry.go:144\\ngithub.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes/pkg/docker/registry.(*Registry).GetImageConfig\\n\\t/go/src/github.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes/pkg/docker/registry/registry.go:103\\nmain.getContainerCmd\\n\\t/go/src/github.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes/cmd/azure-keyvault-secrets-webhook/registry.go:39\\nmain.podWebHook.mutateContainers\\n\\t/go/src/github.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes/cmd/azure-keyvault-secrets-webhook/pod.go:143\\nmain.podWebHook.mutatePodSpec\\n\\t/go/src/github.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes/cmd/azure-keyvault-secrets-webhook/pod.go:299\\nmain.vaultSecretsMutator\\n\\t/go/src/github.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes/cmd/azure-keyvault-secrets-webhook/main.go:163\\ngithub.com/slok/kubewebhook/pkg/webhook/mutating.MutatorFunc.Mutate\\n\\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/slok/kubewebhook@v0.11.0/pkg/webhook/mutating/mutator.go:25\\ngithub.com/slok/kubewebhook/pkg/webhook/mutating.mutationWebhook.mutatingAdmissionReview\\n\\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/slok/kubewebhook@v0.11.0/pkg/webhook/mutating/webhook.go:128\\ngithub.com/slok/kubewebhook/pkg/webhook/mutating.mutationWebhook.Review\\n\\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/slok/kubewebhook@v0.11.0/pkg/webhook/mutating/webhook.go:120\\ngithub.com/slok/kubewebhook/pkg/webhook/internal/instrumenting.(*Webhook).Review\\n\\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/slok/kubewebhook@v0.11.0/pkg/webhook/internal/") has prevented the request from succeeding
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/chip/toolbox/k8s [test ≡ +0 ~2 -0 !]$
```

This has all the markers of the issue describe in here - https://akv2k8s.io/installation/with-aad-pod-identity. But trying to fix it as described does not work:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/chip/toolbox/k8s [test ≡ +0 ~2 -0 !]$ helm -n akv2k8s upgrade akv2k8s akv2k8s/akv2k8s --set addAzurePodIdentityException=true
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: [resource mapping not found for name: "akv2k8s-controller-exception" namespace: "akv2k8s" from "": no matches for kind "AzurePodIdentityException" in version "aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "akv2k8s-env-injector-exception" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "AzurePodIdentityException" in version "aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first]
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/chip/toolbox/k8s [test ≡ +0 ~2 -0 !]$
```

So it does not work either way.

The AKS cluster is deployed using our terraform code. The AKS cluster version is 1.25.4.

**akv2k8s**

```
resource "helm_release" "akv2k8s" {
  name             = "akv2k8s"
  chart            = "akv2k8s"
  version          = "2.3.2"
  create_namespace = true
  namespace        = "akv2k8s"
  repository       = "http://charts.spvapi.no"
}
```

**Our app manifests**

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/chip/toolbox/k8s [test ≡ +0 ~2 -0 !]$ helm get manifest toolbox
---
# Source: chip-toolbox/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: toolbox
  name: toolbox
  namespace: chip
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: toolbox
---
# Source: chip-toolbox/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: toolbox
  name: toolbox
  namespace: chip
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: toolbox
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: toolbox
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: toolbox
          image: app541deploycr.azurecr.io/chip/toolbox:1.0.23062.13
          env:
          - name: DUMMY_SECRET
            value: dummy@azurekeyvault
---
# Source: chip-toolbox/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app: toolbox
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: toolbox
  namespace: chip
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-internal
  rules:
    - host: chip-can.np.dayforcehcm.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /toolbox(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: toolbox
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - chip-can.np.dayforcehcm.com
---
# Source: chip-toolbox/templates/akv.yaml
apiVersion: spv.no/v1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: secret
  namespace: chip
spec:
  vault:
    name: c541chip
    object:
      name: dummy
      type: secret

mark@L-R910LPKW:~/chip/toolbox/k8s [test ≡ +0 ~2 -0 !]$
```

The toolbox image is just nginx:alpine-slim with a few networking tools in it.

I can provide AKS configuration and any logs on demand, I just do not know what is useful up front.

**Additional context**

The terraform code we use to deploy the HELM charts used to deploy AAD Pod Identity HELM chart in the past, but that particular HELM chart was deleted and was never applied to the new cluster. So it is a mystery to me why it happens in the first place.

I have also opened the bug here - https://github.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes/issues/495